# How to copy every single file and folder in Macintosh HD to an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I'm starting fresh with a new install of Big Sur.

I'm trying to make a copy of Macintosh HD. Copy to an external drive. I keep getting this: "The folder “Macintosh HD” can’t be moved into one of its subfolders."

I already have a time machine backup. I'd also like a backup of all the files, including some of the system files, because that's where preferences and set ups are saved. .vimrc is stored in /Users but I'm sure at some point I'm going to need a file found in /System. Otherwise, I would've just backed /Users up.

Comment: You will likely need a backup program to *clone* your HD. I applaud your diligence (a second backup, just in case) but permissions may be getting in your way. Maybe a program like Carbon Copy Cloner or SuperDuper? Both have trial periods and may save you a **lot** of headaches.

Comment: The **Macintosh HD** in a **macOS Big Sur** install is a read-only cryptographically signed image. Keep your **user data** and any _third-party applications_ backed up and you should be good to go along with your **Time Machine** backup.

Comment: Preferences are in /Library/Preferences or the User library folder of the same name. You could use a cloning app lie SuperDuper! to make a disk image of the entire disk. 
Time Machine does however backup all the preference and settings files you are likely to need.

Comment: Carbon Copy Cloner can sort of do this - but can't make the target bootable due to Big Sur restrictions, but that is enough for a reinstall you won't lose data. This https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/macos-big-sur-known-issues explains the issue. I would get CCC or Superduper on trial and use them to do a backup - and a Time Machine one so you have 2 copies before nuking the original

Comment: You can create under Big Sur manually an exact clone of your install on external drive apfs structure. If you give the result of : ``diskutil list `` command, external drive connected, i'l give you the command. This command function only on non m1 Mac.

Comment: APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     456.9 GB   disk1s1 
to
APFS Container Scheme -                      +649.9 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s3